# how to Assign name to drop down options

Tags: php, phalcon

Using Phalcon framework, I have a Form class file where I declare `select` and `render` in `.volt` file:

```
$soc_bulding =  new Select("soc_building_id", $options['soc_bulding'], 
    array('using' => array('soc_building_id', 'soc_building_name'), 
          "class" => "mandatory-field") );
$soc_bulding->setLabel("Buiding name" . REQ_FIELD);
$this->add($soc_bulding);
```

in the above code, `'using' => array('soc_building_id', 'soc_building_name')` reflect `soc_building_id` as option value and `soc_building_name` actual text in drop down option, but I want one more property name in that same option box, already tried to pass 3 parameter to that array but it's not working.

Comment: Straightforward its not possible. But you can take exaples from [this](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/895/addoption-method-of-forms-element-select-object-does-not-seem-to) topic on Phalcons' forum.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the code below and replace yours

```
echo $this->tag->select(array("users",
        Users::find(),
        "useEmpty"  =>  true,
        "emptyText" =>  "Please select",
        "using" => array("id", "name"),
     ));
```

Comment: "using" => array("id", "name") have two parameters consider as option name and value it not allow 3rd attribute .... thank you for help